# Run Publish-AzureRmVMDscConfiguration without logging in

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

How can I pack a configuration archive without logging in? I want to run this command in an automation context:

```
Publish-AzureRmVMDscConfiguration -Force -ConfigurationPath .\AppServer.ps1 -ConfigurationArchivePath .\AppServer.ps1.zip
```

There are no calls out to the network, I'm not performing any subscription operations that require authorization, I just want it to make me a nice zip file with the cmdlet. However, when I try, it fails:

```
Publish-AzureRmVMDscConfiguration : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
```

This seems silly to me but I went ahead and checked Get-Help. I can't find anything that looks helpful though. How can I pack up my DSC configuration without having to run `Login-AzureRmAccount`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a "design limitation" - you might start by filing an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell

As a workaround, depending on the "sophistication" of your DSC config, you can just create a zip file yourself.  If you have additional/non-default modules or resources, you'd need to put those in the archive as well (which is what the cmdlet helps with)...